# How to return value in VueJS Mixin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource, vue-component

I'm currently developing a webapp in Vuejs. I created a Mixin that I can access globally which handles any request to my api:

```
export default {

  data() {
    return {
      apiURL: 'http://example.com/api',
      timeout: 10000,
    };
  },

  methods: {

    callAPI(method, url, body) {
      this.$http({
        url: this.apiURL + url,
        method,
        body,
        timeout: this.timeout,
      })
      .then((response) =>
        response,
      (response) => {
        if (response.data.error) {
            this.error = response.data.error;
        } else {
          this.error = 'We can\'t connect to the server. Please try again in a few minutes.';
        }
        return response;
      });
      // return 'test';
    },

  },

};
```

Now, in some of my components I call the api function:

```
const api_response = this.callAPI('POST', '/auth', credentials);
alert (api_response);
```

It works fine, but one thing doesn't work as expected. I expect my `api_response` constant to have the value of `response` but it is always `undefined`. So every time I got this alert with `undefined`. How is that possible? When I uncomment the `return 'test'` line it works: I got an alert with `test`, but it doesn't seem to work within the `this.$http` part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `callAPI` has no `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`. If it returned your `$http` call, it still would not give you `response`, but would be [a `Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you would want to do something like

```
let api_response;
this.callAPI('POST', '/auth', credentials).then((response) => api_response = response);
```

Comment: Thank you. Another option is to do `return this.$http({...`

Comment: If you `return this.$http({...` you will get a Promise, not a value.